# Help creating a table of success drawing double, triple or quadruple repeats .

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

I'm making this table.

You have classic cards from A to 10. 4 of every number. So 40 cards.

It's a hand, so you have one less card on every draw.

I want to calculate the repeats. (only in the numbers)

[image]
* *numbers are rounded*

I'm basically ignorant on maths, even this basic, so I didn't understand how I to continue now.

I was calculating the probabilities to at least one repeat, but now I want to calculate the probabilities to obtain a double, a triple and a quadruple.

I have to take in account that now when you have a triple, you didn't have a double and the same for the quadruple and triple.

**How can I calculate the rest?**

Comment: So you mean, that if you have 8 8 8 8 (four eights), you want to count it as 1 "triple repeat" but not as a "double repeat", right? (It's not 100% clear)

Comment: If you have four eights, that count as a quadruple and not as a double or a triple. (Ignoring the 2 doubles here, it just "At least one double %") Sorry for the bad explanation. Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: Do you put the cards back in the stack at the end of a draw ? (if you do, the math will be easier)

Comment: No, it's a hand. You have one less card every time.

Comment: It think you will have no other choice than to write a huge probability tree:
say you first card is `a`, then for your second draw, you have 3 other `a`, and 39 cards left. You will have $${3}\over{39}$$ probabilities to have `aa`, and $${36}\over{39}$$ to have `ab`.

Comment: Didn't understand from where you obtain those numbers to make the division.

Comment: @Malkev: You have 4 cards of each category. You have a total of 40 cards. If you get one card from category `a`, you only have 3 cards left in that category, and since you took a card, you only have 39 cards left.

Comment: So 3/39 * 36/39. But what I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a deck of 4 Ones, 4 Twos, ... ,4 Tens.

You can write the individual situations as tupels. The tupel will denote how many Ones, Twos, .... , Tens you have after drawn K cards. E.g. $(0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$ denotes that you have drawn 3 cards in total, your draw consisting of 2 Threes and 1 Ten.

Now the probability for drawing such a tupel is given by the multivariate hypergeometric distribution. When you have drawn $K$ cards, consisting of $k_1$ Ones,  $k_2$ Twos,  ..., $k_{10}$ Tens, 
you have

$$
p(k_1,k_2, ... , k_{10}) = \frac{{4 \choose k_1} {4 \choose k_2}\cdots {4 \choose k_{10}} }{{40 \choose K}}
$$

So for the above example, 
$$
p(0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) = \frac{{4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1}}{{40 \choose 3}} = 0.0024
$$

Now for your table, you can sum up the probabilities of all tuples which lead to the desired result.

E.g. 2 draws, 1 double (you have that already):

$$
p(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) = \frac{{4 \choose 2}}{{40 \choose 2}} = 0.0077
$$

You can have the 2 at ten positions, so you get

$P($ 2 draws, 1 double$) = 10  \; p(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) = 0.077$

Next: 3 draws, 1 double:

$$
p(2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) = 0.0024
$$ 
(see above)

You can have the 2 at ten positions, and for each of these positions you can have  the 1 at nine positions, so you get

$P($ 3 draws, 1 double$) = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot   0.0024 = 0.2160$

Next: 3 draws, 1 triple:

$$
p(3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) = \frac{{4 \choose 3} }{{40 \choose 3}} = 0.000405
$$

You can have the 3 at ten positions, so you get

$P($ 3 draws, 1 triple$) = 10 \cdot 0.000405 = 0.00405$

This concludes the 3 draws.

You will have to sum up increasingly many different situations as you go to 4 draws and higher. It may be a bit tedious but it works.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand how to positionate the numbers, but I don't understand how to calculate it. (4/3) / (40/3) does not give me 0.000405. Sorry for being that ignorant.

Comment: Dear Malkev, $ {4 \choose 3} $ and the other entities are not fractions but binomial coefficients, see e.g. here  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)  for computation, also in MATLAB this can be computed directly by the command nchoosek(4,3) .

Comment: Ok! I understand now this point. Last problem I having is with the draws more than 4. For example 7 draws and a quadruple. I have to start with (4,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) and end with (4,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)? Because you can't draw more than 4. Is this correct? Then I have to multiply it for 10*9*8*7?

Comment: Multiplying with 10*9*8*7 would be overcounting, since it doesn't matter if your first 1 is on position 2, say, and the second 1 is on position 3, or the other way around. If there are multiple entries with the same number, e.g. as in your example, 3 times the 1, and if you have 9 positions available for these, than the number of arrangements is    ${9 \choose 3}$. So the total for one 4 and three 1's is   $10 \cdot  {9 \choose 3}$.

Comment: Before you run into trouble, here is the general case. Example:  (1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0). How many cases of two doubles and 3 singles are there in total? More generally: If you have a tupel of N (here:10) and if you want to arrange D different events in this tupel (here: D = 3 events: doubles, singles and none's), and if these events occur $k_1, k_2, ... , k_d$ times (here: k1 =2 (doubles), k2 = 3 (singles), k3 = 5 (none's)), with $k_1+ k_2 +  ... + k_d = N$, then the total arrangement number  is  the  multinomial $N \choose {k_1, k_2, ... , k_d} $  = $\frac{N !}{k_1 ! k_2 ! \cdots k_d !} $